# SalesforceOne / iPhone Focus Issue

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning-design-system

I am having an issue with the Lightning Design System and iPhone:

Within Salesforce1 app or safari browser, when a user is viewing a Visual Force page and has a height greater then the screen height,  if  tap on any element in the bottom of the page, the Visual Force page scrolls to the top and the user loses focus on the area of the page they were in.

I have tried the suggested work around in this article: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T2oLAAS

but it does not work and this issue is also present in iOS10, not just iOS8.  Has anyone run into this?  Have any suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code `html, body { height: 100%; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }`, it work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify original script so it will work

```
<script> 
(function(){try{var a=navigator.userAgent; 
if((a.indexOf('Salesforce')!=-1)&&(a.indexOf('iPhone')!=-1||a.indexOf('iPad')!=-1) &&(a.indexOf('Safari')==-1)){ 
var s=document.createElement('style'); 
s.innerHTML="html,html body{overflow: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;}body{position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;}"; 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);}}catch(e){}})(); 
</script>
```

I have removed `Ios` 8 from if condition so it will work on all IOS devices.